# How do I bind a ZFS pool to a LXC container?

Tags: virtualization, lxc, zfs

I'm using Ubuntu Server 11.10 Oneric, kernel 3.0.0-14-server.

I installed ZFS from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable) and created zpool and mounted it at **/zfstankdir**.

Then I installed LXC and created Ubuntu container.

Now I want to bind **/zfstankdir** to **/mycontainer/rootfs/zfstankdir**

So I did it in Host machine through **/etc/fstab**

```
/zfstankdir /mycontainer/rootfs/zfstankdir      none defaults,bind      0       0
```

But in lxc container I see content of the **/zfstankdir** mount point directory instead of **zpool** content.

Question is: how to bind to container content of **zpool**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bind is happening before ZFS is ready.

You need the enhanced `mountall` utility from the daily PPA.  Run `apt-add-repository ppa:zfs-native/daily`, do a full upgrade, and try again.

If the problem persists, then please open an issue here:

https://github.com/dajhorn/pkg-zfs/issues/new

Comment: Thanks Darik. I just added daily repository and did a full upgrade. Now in my LXC container I see contents of zpool!